# How can getDerivedStateFromProps method can access state if the state is initialized from within the constructor(props)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Hi all I am new to `ES6` and `React` and I am stuck in component lifecycle-creation of react. My question is In my constructor I have initialized state..

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    ....something
}
```

Now in the Component Lifecycle Creation in react we have `getDerivedStateFromProps`  which is a static function which takes two arguments props and previous state and you might return the current state or so depending if you are changing the state from props or not

```js
static getDerivedStateFromProps (props, state) {
    ... do something
    return state;
}
```

How is this static function able to access or have a property which is initialized in `constructor()` which will run at runtime or when the object is created ? Isn't the static function runs before runtime at class loading time so how is it able to access state object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and you might return the current state or so depending if you are changing the state from props or not

No, you return a state *update* (things to change, not complete state [although complete state is okay too]), or don't return anything / return `undefined` for no update.

> How is this static function able to access or have a property which is initialized in constructor() which will run at runtime or when the object is created ?

It doesn't. React calls the function *passing in* the state as an argument, as you said. Think of the React code that calls this as looking vaguely like this:

```
const stateUpdate = YourComponentClass.getDerivedStateFromProps(
    componentInstance.state,
    componentInstance.props
);
// (Then it uses `stateUpdate` to set the state immediately)
```

I'm sure it's not really that, but conceptually, that's what it's doing.

`getDerivedStateFromProps` is static so that people don't do things in it that mutate the instance, because they don't have access to the instance.